# Filling a column based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Using dummy data for this, I have two data frames:

One is a list of locations and their rankings on a measurement separated by gender (df1)

```
  Locations Male Female
1         A    1      2
2         B    2      1
3         C    1      2
```

The other is a list of people

```
   Name Gender Location
1   Joe   Male        A
2  Alex Female        B
3 Chris Female        A
4   Sam   Male        C
```

I want to add a column to the second data frame (df2$Value) that gives the corresponding number for each person from the first data frame based on their gender and location. (So in this case the results would be 1,1,2,1).

I've tried playing around with merge and with some conditional statements, but to no avail.

Comment: `df2 %>% mutate(Value = df1[match(Location,df1$Locations),Gender] %>% as.matrix %>% diag())`

Answer (score 4):

Convert df1 into a stacked format with matching names:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% gather(Gender, Value, Male:Female)
names(df1)[names(df1)=="Locations"] <- "Location"
```

Using `left_join` to match the `Value` by `Gender` and `Location`:

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1)

#    Name Gender Location Value
# 1   Joe   Male        A     1
# 2  Alex Female        B     1
# 3 Chris Female        A     2
# 4   Sam   Male        C     1
```